# Is there a way to pause Stardew Valley in multiplayer?

Tags: stardew-valley

In multiplayer the days go by FAST. You really realise that Stardew usually pauses everytime you are in a cutscene or menu, and that is lost when you are playing multiplayer.

The clock is always running.

But if there is something of an emergency, like i need to leave right now because the pizza guy is at the door... Is there a way to still pause the game at any point during the day?

Comment: I thought all users get pulled into the cutscene when one user activates one? Or did a recent update change that?

Comment: As of now, in Online play, cutscenes are separate. What is funny is that if the other player doesn't have that cutscene, they can run around in the cutscene while Shane is having an epiphany about his alcoolism.

Comment: To correct, there are a few cutscences that as soon as one player is taken, it brings everybody in it. Like the 'Discovering the community center' one, pretty early. But all the heart events are separate.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The host can use the `/pause` command and that pauses the game for all players. You can also type `/resume` to... Well, resume playing.

Comment: /pause also resumes the game

Answer (score 4):

I've only verified this in local multiplayer, but if everyone is in a situation that would pause the game (for example, opening the menu) then time will pause.  That requires a bit more coordination, though.

Comment: Have already tried that, and Im pretty sure it doesnt.

Comment: @Fredy31 It does, I just checked. If all players have a dialog open, the game is paused and the clock is flashing in the background for both players.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in local (split screen) multiplayer.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not work in online play- my friend and I still had time pass while we were watching the community centre restoration.

Comment: Really wonder if /pause would pause cutscenes or let them playout without time passing. Would be useful. I had a few times where I had an event that could only happen late nights and I would just pass out on cutscene end.